# Rolling 13 weeks in Microsoft sql

Tags: sql-server, week-number

I'm trying to get data for the rolling 13 weeks, but not sure how to do it correctly.

I have tried this:

```
DATEDIFF(week,Completed_date,GETDATE()) < 13
```

But I get 14 weeks instead of 13 and I think this might get me incorrect results as it goes 91 days back so it might not get to the start of week..

Comment: It's based on the `@@Datefirst` look in to this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187766.aspx

Comment: If this is in where clause it's usually better from performance point of view to use something like CompletedDate >= dateadd... so that indexes can be used.

Comment: my query does get the correct number, but it does it for 14 months..don't now were the problem is with this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DATEDIFF with week uses calendar weeks. You may want to use day if you are expecting this to be a set number of days rolling rather than aligning to calendar weeks. Also, make sure you account for time of day if you are using GETDATE().

This article below can help you as well, especially the remark,

> Specifying SET DATEFIRST has no effect on DATEDIFF. DATEDIFF always
>   uses Sunday as the first day of the week to ensure the function is
>   deterministic.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Comment: I expect this to count records processed every week for past 13 weeks including current one.